# use lib for paths relative to a module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm having issues figuring out relative paths for `use lib`.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

I have a directory call `foo`, which contains a script named `myscript.pl`.  `myscript.pl` uses a module named `Mod1.pm` located in a subdirectory called `bar`, so at the top of `myscript.pl` I put the lines:

```
    use lib 'bar';
    use Mod1;
```

This works fine, until I want `Mod1.pm` to use another module, `foo/bar/asdf/Mod2.pm`.  If I put a `use lib 'asdf'` at the top of `Mod1.pm` this won't work because it searches relative to the directory I'm running `myscript.pl` from.  So I did some searching and found `FindBin`, and tried adding these lines to Mod1.pm:

```
    use FindBin;
    use lib "$FindBin::Bin/asdf";
```

This didn't work either, because `FindBin` finds the directory that the script I am running (`myscript.pl`) is located in, not the file that uses `FindBin` (in this case `Mod1.pm`).  So my question is, is there a way to search relative to where `Mod1.pm` is located, so that it can find `Mod2.pm` no matter where the script that uses `Mod1.pm` is located?

EDIT:  Further explanation of my situation to address some of your comments:

I'm working on code in a repository, and all CPAN libraries need to be installed in a directory in the repository.  That means that the `use lib`s can't have any absolute paths.  For my project there is a central module "Mod1.pm" which `use`es quite a few CPAN modules that are located in various directories in the repository.  All of the `use lib` statements are of the form `use lib '../../foo/bar/asdf'` so that they can be found relative to wherever you're running the script from, but this restricts where you can run scripts that use Mod1.pm, which I'm trying to avoid.  Another annoying side effect is that I can't just `perl -c Mod1.pm` to make sure any edits I make to Mod1.pm are sane, unless I'm running it in the right place, which conveniently isn't where Mod1.pm is located.  Oh the joys of joining a project that already has messy code in place...  Another nasty side effect is that I can't use any CPAN modules that any of you are suggesting to fix my problems, because I'd still need a way to find those.

Comment: Try `use lib 'bar/asdf';` in Mod1.pm

Comment: @chrsblck That only works if I'm running the script from foo.  I want it to work regardless of where I'm running it from, or where the script is located.

Comment: Well then you can try using Absolute paths, or you can add these directories to your `$PERL5LIB`

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but I have to check this code into a repository, and who knows what the absolute path for anyone else who uses this code will be...

Comment: It is that easy. Just commit the directories with the code. Then when this code is checked out the get everything. Have you ever pulled any source from CPAN?

Comment: Modules should not touch @INC (or use `use lib`). That's a mess.

Comment: In your case it would be best to use `-I` option while running the perl script. `perl -Ipath/to/dir -Ipath/to/dir/subdir myscript.pl`. This works. Run from anywhere and replace relative path from there to modules in perl command.

Comment: Could you talk some about why you need this setup?  Its a bit tortured and it is very unusual to want to change the load path inside a library.  Whatever problem you're trying to solve with that solution, there's probably a better way.  Maybe you could show the file layout of your project?

Comment: You mention CPAN libraries are installed in "located in various directories in the repository", why not in one directory?  This would appear to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Well, they're all installed in the same root directory, but when you install a CPAN module it creates subdirectories like `lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8` or `lib64/perl5/vendor_perl` etc.  I didn't do it, I just joined the project and I'm not really allowed to rearrange the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Usually* you want your main program to find all its libraries on its own, in which case you should do as Alec Chen answered.

In some situations, such as finding plug ins, you want a library to find other libraries relative to its location.

You can do this using [`__FILE__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__FILE__.html) which contains the location of the current file of source code.

```
package Mod1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

# Must put this in a BEGIN block so it happens at "compile time" while the
# "use"s are being executed.  But the "my" declaration must happen outside
# the BEGIN block else it can't be seen.
my $module_dir;
BEGIN { $module_dir = dirname(__FILE__); }

use lib $module_dir;

use Mod2;
```

The funny way that's written above is because each Perl file has two (or more) stages of execution.  "Compile time" and "run time".  `use` statements happen at compile time.  In order to `use lib $module_dir`, we must set `$module_dir` at compile time with a `BEGIN` block.  Confused?  There's easier ways...

It is bad form for a module to alter `@INC` globally.  Loading a module should not change the global state of the program (unless that's part of its functionality).  You would instead localize it.

```
package Mod1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
my $module_dir = dirname(__FILE__);

{
    local @INC;
    push @INC, $module_dir;
    require Mod2;
}
```

But its probably simpler to just require it directly as a file.

```
package Mod1;

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;
my $module_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
require File::Spec->catfile($module_dir, "Mod2.pm");
```

And, this being Perl, there are modules to handle having plugins, [Module::Pluggable](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aPluggable) being very popular.

Comment: I tried option 1 (but with `use lib ($module_dir . '/asdf')`), but my script fails to compile, and the error message says that @INC contains `'bar'` and `'/asdf'`.  I would have expected @INC to contain `'bar/asdf'`, so I'm not sure what's going on here...  Perhaps I am misunderstanding how `use lib` works?  (Option 3 worked for me, but I can't use that in my actual work for unrelated reasons, which the comment char limit is too small to contain.)

Comment: @Lorkenpeist My mistake. If you turn on strict and warnings (which you should always do and I neglected in my examples) you'll see that `$module_dir` is undefined.  I corrected the code and added an explanation. Perhaps you can add why option 3 is not possible in your post? That's a strange restriction, not being able to use File::Spec or require.  Or do you mean using Module::Pluggable?

Comment: Added more info to my post.  Basically it would be a pain to find where all of the CPAN modules are located (all the `use lib` statements come first, then the `use` statements, so it's not obvious which `use`es go with each `use lib`).  I guess I can go digging, because I do like the looks of option 3 and I'll try to make it work.  My other concern is that some of the `use` statements are of the form `use Mod blah`, and I don't know how to do that for `require`.  The perldoc page for require doesn't have a 2-argument version.

Comment: Actually, it looks like option 1 (now that it's fixed) allows me to fix it with the least changes to the existing code.  All I have to do is change the `use lib` statements to use `$module_dir` instead of `../../foo/bar` and it works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should `use lib` in `myscript.pl`, which is a convention.

For example, your files are organized as:

```
.
├── bar
│   ├── Mod1.pm
│   └── asdf
│       └── Mod2.pm
└── myscript.pl
```

then `use lib` in `myscript.pl`:

```perl
use File::Spec;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib File::Spec->catdir($Bin, 'bar');
use Mod1;
```

then use `Mod1.pm` and `Mod2.pm` just like using other CPAN modules. Just remember to add the dir name before the module name when using `Mod2.pm`.

in `Mod1.pm`:

```perl
package Mod1;

use asdf::Mod2;

1;
```

in `Mod2.pm`:

```perl
package asdf::Mod2;

1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid that option won't work for me, because in my actual work "Mod1" includes quite a few other modules, and it would be a pain to `use` them in every single script that uses Mod1, of which there are, unfortunately, quite a few.  Not to mention that many of the included modules are CPAN libraries that depend on other libraries and probably wouldn't play nice if I changed the `package` line...

Comment: sounds like what you needs is [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm)