# Force locally installed module to use locally installed dependencies

Tags: perl, dependencies, perl-module, cpan, dependency-management

I'm working on a project that requires all third-party (read: CPAN) perl modules to be installed in a perforce repository, so that any code that depends on them can be successfully run without anyone else needing to manually install them.   I use cpanminus to install my CPAN modules, so I ran `cpanm -L . Moose` in the desired directory, and everything installed successfully.  However, when I try to compile a module I made with Moose, I sometimes get this error:

```
Undefined subroutine &Carp::longmess_heavy called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Carp.pm line 235.
```

It looks like, even though Carp was installed into my local directory with Moose, it is using the (outdated) version in `/user/lib/perl5/5.8.8`.  I could upgrade Carp on my machine, but as soon as I check my code into the repository everyone else with their outdated Carps will run into the same issue.  So how do I force Moose to use the locally installed Carp, rather than the one in `/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.  It's messy, but that's the price I have to pay for joining a project that already has a messy system in place.

Before including Moose, I have to explicitly required the new Carp:

```
require "[path to Carp]/Carp.pm";
```

This generated a lot of warnings about redefining subroutines, so I had to (temporarily) suppress them:

```
my $restore_warn = $SIG{'__WARN__'};
$SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub {};
require "[path to Carp]/Carp.pm";
$SIG{'__WARN__'} = $restore_warn;
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't force Moose, you force `perl`. You've installed the module in a location `perl` doesn't know anything about, so you need to tell `perl` about it.

Since you want to affect all scripts, you'd want to place in your login script.

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/.../lib
```

If you wanted to only affect that one program, you'd launch the program using the following:

```
PERL5LIB=/home/.../lib script
```

or you'd add the following to your script:

```
use lib '/home/.../lib';
```

Comment: This is correct, but isn't very portable.
I would recommend using local::lib.  http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm#The_bootstrapping_technique

Comment: @misplacedme, 1) local::lib is just an unportable. (In fact, it's extremely complicated to use in a login script.) 2) local::lib uses INSTALL_BASE, which I believe is flawed by design.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I'll keep this in mind next time I need to do this.

Comment: The first option unfortunately wouldn't work because that would require everyone on the project (there are quite a few of us) to manually update their login scripts.  Second option wouldn't work for similar reasons... As for the third option, I'm already doing that.  Well, more specifically, I'm using the technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15307467/2124637

Comment: If everyone on the project is capable of installing modules in a  non-standard location, they are capable of modifying their login script.

Comment: And if you're using that technique, you are including the wrong directory or you are doing it too late (perhaps because you are changing @INC in a module, something that makes no sense.)

Comment: Actually I am changing @INC in a module.  Could you please explain why that doesn't work?

Comment: I didn't say changing @INC in a module didn't work; I said it makes no sense. As for why it doesn't work, I gave you two possible reasons.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase.  Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26675/discussion-between-lorkenpeist-and-ikegami)